# Active Directory User restriction in Linux servers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, su

We have integrated Linux servers with Active Directory and able to login with AD users within Linux servers, but here all the users who are in Active Directory are able to log in from a user profile to root i.e., able to perform `su` to root.
We tried changing the following file to restrict user access to `su`:

```
vi /etc/pam.d/su
```

and uncommented the below line:

```
auth required pam_wheel.so group=xxxxx
```

But here all the users along with remaining AD users and Linux users are restricted to use 'su'.
I'm not able to restrict this to a particular user or group.
Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.